# Displaying an image in pdf file generated by snappy

Tags: symfony, twig, snappy

I want to add an image to my pdf generated by snappy ,but nothing appear

**In my twig :**

I am persisting the name of the file in my data base, survey.event.image contain the name of the image

```
<div style="margin-top: 26px; width: 200px">

    <img   src="{{ asset('uploads/imagesFile/'~survey.event.image) }}" id="imgEvent">

</div>
```

**I have enabled images =>true**

```
return new Response(
    $this->get('knp_snappy.pdf')->getOutputFromHtml($html,array(
        'default-header'=>null,
        'encoding' => 'utf-8',
        'images' => true,
        'enable-javascript' => true,
        'margin-right'  => 7,
        'margin-left'  =>7,
        'javascript-delay' => 5000
    )),
    200,
    array(
        'Content-Type'          => 'application/pdf',
        'Content-Disposition'   => 'attachment; filename="file1.pdf"'
    )
);
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to use `absolute_url` to get absolute assets url

```
<div style="margin-top: 26px; width: 200px">

<img   src="{{ absolute_url(asset('uploads/imagesFile/'~survey.event.image)) }}" id="imgEvent">
```

Comment: undefined function

Comment: Note - this solution works great with Symfony with twig

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone is still for a solution.
In my Laravel 8 i was able to load the image but while downloading the image it takes a while to load & then failed to download. I was using snappy for pdf generate & download.

Here's how i solve it.

From this

```
<img src="{{asset('assets/images/czm/bismillah.png')}}" width="10%" alt="">
```

To this. I just remove laravel default asset and convert the image into base64.

```
<img src="{{'data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode(file_get_contents(public_path('assets/images/czm/bismillah.png')))}}" width="180"/>
```

You can find more [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-include-an-image-into-pdf-using-barryvdh-snappy)

Answer (score 0):

Use absolute=true for your path to the image.

```
<img src="{{ asset('uploads/imagesFile/'~survey.event.image, , absolute=true) }}" id="imgEvent">
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the image path is wrong, try this :

```
<div style="width: 200px; height: auto;">
  <img src="{{ pathToWeb }}/uploads/imagesFile/image.jpg" alt="img">
</div>
```

And add this in your config.yml :

```
# Twig Configuration
twig:
  globals:
    pathToWeb: "%kernel.root_dir%/../web"
```

Comment: OP is using asset function to determine the location

Comment: Yeah but why should OP switch from `asset` to just an absolute path. Makes no sense

Comment: when I use `asset`, the image is not found when I create the pdf. Use a absolute path is not the better solution but in this case I not find some thing better